# ErrorDocument 404 .htaccess not working with RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

`.htaccess` `ErrorDocument 404` page  not redirecting when I was using the rewrite rule. Getting 500 Internal Server Error.

Without `RewriteRule` the `ErrorDocument` is Working fine.

**My Code**

```
   RewriteEngine On 
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /stores/$1  [NC,L]
   ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: In your rule you are rewriting every non-file, non-directory request to `/stores/...` and also trying to use `404.html` for not found URIs. You have to decide which one to keep.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /stores/$1  [NC,L]
> ```

The "problem" with this rule is that if you make a request for a non-existent file and that file not exist in the `/stores/` subdirectory either then it will result in an endless rewrite-loop (hence the 500 Internal Server Error you are seeing) since it will attempt to rewrite as follows:

- `/not-exists` (initial request)
- `/stores/not-exists` (1st rewrite)
- `/stores/stores/not-exists` (2nd pass)
- `/stores/stores/stores/not-exists` (3rd pass)
- etc.

You've not actually stated what you are trying to achieve here, but I assume `/stores` is a "hidden" subdirectory and you are intending to rewrite to actual files within the `/stores` subdirectory. This is the only way a rule like this would work with an `ErrorDocument 404` directive defined in Apache.

So, when rewriting to the `/stores` subdirectory, you need to first check that the request would map to an actual file *before* issuing the rewrite. That way, any request that does not exist and does not map to a file in the `/stores` subdirectory will drop through to the Apache defined 404 `ErrorDocument`.

For example, try the following instead:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On 

# Rewrite request to "/stores" directory if file exists in that directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/stores/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+) stores/$1 [L]

# (OPTIONAL) Rewrite requests for root to "/stores/"
RewriteRule ^$ stores/ [L]
```

The `<IfModule>` container is not required (but you had the `RewriteEngine` directive outside of this container - which defeats the point anyway).

The `RewriteBase` directive is not required here if the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root.

It is structurally better to define your `ErrorDocument`s first.

Comment: Thank you, but getting another issue ...... Without extention( .php) folder (stores) Pages not working Help me with that –